# Why is this Apache 2.2 SetEnvIf directive failing?

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm trying to solve a very annoying problem that requires me to set a header from my .htaccess file, but only for a specific URL.

As a test of the concept, I have the following rules in my .htaccess file:

```
SetEnv REFERRER_POLICY "no-cats"
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/sales/referral$ CHIMP_POLICY=eat-bananas
Header set Cat-policy %{Request_URI}e
Header set Dog-policy %{REFERRER_POLICY}e
Header set Chimp-policy %{CHIMP_POLICY}e env=CHIMP_POLICY
Header set Human-policy %{CHIMP_POLICY}e
```

When I visit https://example.com/sales/referral, I see the following headers:

```
Cat-policy: /sales/referral
Dog-policy: no-cats
Human-policy: (null)
```

Clearly CHIMP_POLICY is not being set, but as the Cat-policy header shows, the Request_URI does contain exactly the string that should match the Regex used in SetEnvIf and the syntax used in SetEnvIf matches that used in the [Apache 2.2 documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif)

I don't understand why it's failing at all!

Comment: Why do you have `e` at the end of Header set lines? Why do you have `env=CHIMP_POLICY` at the end of line? Did you make a mistake while copying or is it that exactly your `.htacces` file?

Comment: @nobody I thought that %{variable}e was the syntax for fetching the value of environment variables. Is that not correct? The env=CHIMP_POLICY is intended to make this a conditional statement - it sets the Chimp-policy header if the CHIMP_POLICY environment variable is set.

Comment: You are right. I looked into the documentation and all seems correctly setup. Maybe you should use quotes `"`. Like this: `Header set Cat-policy "%{Request_URI}e"` or `Header set Chimp-policy "%{CHIMP_POLICY}e" "env=CHIMP_POLICY"`

Comment: Apache 2.2 or 2.4? Probably does not change anything  for your specific problem but your link points to the 2.4 documentation. And also, if there are no strong reasons to stick with 2.2, you should upgrade to 2.4

Comment: Where is this configuration really stored, is your .htaccess at the root of the server web directory? I would recommend putting the configuration statements in the global Apache configuration, it is always better than the .htaccess files.

Comment: I’m a year late and this only applies to 2.4, but here’s what’s going on: https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/httpd-subrequest-variable-inconsistencies.html